# Where is IIS output cache location, and how can I relocate it?

Tags: iis, cache

I've successfully configured IIS output cache. However after repeated google pagespeed tests it seems that the page speed is even slower with output caching compared to without output cache configuration.

My guess it is because the very slow system drive. I have an SSD data drive too in the system, so just for the proof of concept I would like to test a configuration where the IIS output cache is on that drive.

I found the application pool temp folder, and the temp compressed files folder, what are have some information how to relocate them, but I think neither is the output cache disk location.

Is it possible to relocate the output cache location?

Answer (score 2):

I think IIS keeps it's cache in memory rather than on disk. Most cached items are static resources, what would be the point to cache them on disk when they are already on disk?